Clicking on the taskbar calendar opens notifications in my Windows 11
I would like to get a calendar, I mean the simple calendar to allow me to see next weeks days, when I click on the calendar icon in the taskbar (bottom right icon),
Just Like it did in the past 15 years.. instead of these useless forced MS notifications
Is it possible?.

